# Rust async and AsRef<P: Path> not being Send

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a following code:

```
pub async fn connect<P: AsRef<Path>>(&self, path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    sleep(a_while).await;
    return self.socket.connect(path.as_ref());
}
```

And I get following clippy error:

```
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
note: `P` doesn't implement `std::marker::Send`
```

Now, I am quite sure there are async functions in tokio that take `AsRef<Path>`, e.g.,[`UnixDatagram::send_to`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.UnixDatagram.html#method.send_to).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to say that anything that implements `AsRef<Path>` is `path`. The thing is that because `connect` can be another thread, you need to add the constraint to `P` that it also has to be `Send` because `connect` can cross thread boundaries.

So:

```
 pub async fn connect<P: AsRef<Path> + Send>(&self, path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    sleep(a_while).await;
    return self.socket.connect(path.as_ref());
}
```

But the other issue is that since `P` is a reference so it also has to be `Sync` so you need a further constraint that:

```
 pub async fn connect<P: AsRef<Path> + Send + Sync>(&self, path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    sleep(a_while).await;
    return self.socket.connect(path.as_ref());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted out the issue. Still, I am bit confused why they don't do the same thing in https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.UnixDatagram.html#method.send_to ? Why are they ok with just having AsRef<Path> there? Any ideas?

Comment: That is a good question  I'll have a look and get back to you

Comment: I figured it out. So the compiler will annotate send and sync as needed automatically, but there's something about your code that is forcing that annotation to be explicitly put on.

Answer (score 2):

You did nothing wrong. It's the lint that is fired incorrectly. There is a reason it is allow-by-default (https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#future_not_send).

*If* the user will supply with a non-`Send` `P`, there will be an error. The same is true for `UnixDatagram::send_to()`. This situation is very unlikely, though, as paths are usually `Path` or `&str` (or more rarely `&OsStr`) which are all `Send + Sync`.

Just `#[allow(clippy::future_not_send)]`, either globally or for this function.

Comment: Alternatively, call `path.as_ref()` before the `await` point, this way `path` does not need to be held across the await point, and thus its send-ability is not a factor.

Comment: "If the user will supply with a non-Send P, there will be an error." there wil be an error if it's used in a runtime / context which requires `Send` futures no?

Comment: @Masklinn Of course, only if `Send` is required. Using `as_ref()` will not help, we still need the original object alive because `as_ref()` is called with reference to it and produces reference with the same lifetime.

Comment: @Masklinn but ‘as_ref’ doesn’t consume, so ‘path’ will actually survive, am I wrong?